# ¿Como puedo sumar un producto que fue ingresado anteriormente y que no se liste como si fuera uno nuevo?

Tags: mysql, laravel, reactjs

Tengo un metodo handleChange que recive un event.target.value que es el codigo del producto que se ingresa en el input, y otro metodo al que le hago un map mandandole un indice y un e, lo que necesito es que cuado yo ingrese un producto o codigo de producto que ya eh ingresado o que ya esta en la tabla que le muestro al cliente me lo sume al producto que con anterioridad ya habia ingreaso.

```
handleChange(event) {  
    axios({  
      method: "post",  
      url: `${URL}/entrada/tabla/${event.target.value}`,  
      headers: {  
        Authorization: "bearer " + localStorage.token  
      }  
    })  
      .then(respuesta => {  
        let r = respuesta.data;  

        if (r.ok) {  
          var cant2 = document.getElementById("txt_cant_prod").value || 0;  

          if (cant2 === 0) {    
            cant2 = 1;    
          }  

          if (cant2 < 0) {  
            if (!this.notificationSystem) {  
              return;  
            }  

            this.notificationSystem.addNotification({  
              title: <MdImportantDevices />,  
              message: "La cantidad no esta disponible",  
              level: "error"  
            });  

            document.getElementById("id_producto").reset();    
            document.getElementById("txt_cant_prod").reset();  
            document.getElementById("hola").reset();  

            return;  
          }  
          // if (cant2 === 0) {  
          //   cant2 = 1;  
          // }  

          document.getElementById("hola").reset();  

          r.data.cantidad = cant2;  
          let data = this.state.productos;  

          data.push(r.data);  

          // this.setState({  
          //   productos: data,   
          //   entradap:{  
          //     id_producto:"",  
          //     cantidad:""  
          //   }  

          // });   
          setTimeout(() => {  
            this.setState({  
              productos: data,  
              entradap: {  
                id_producto: "",  
                cantidad: ""  
              }  
            });  
          }, 100);  
          this.entradap.cantidad = "";  

          document.getElementById("id_producto").reset();  
          document.getElementById("txt_cant_prod").reset();  
        } else if (r.ok === false) {  
          document.getElementById("hola").reset();  
          this.entradap.cantidad = "";  
          document.getElementById("id_producto").reset();  
          document.getElementById("txt_cant_prod").reset();  
        }  
      })  
      .catch(error => {  
        console.log(error);  
      });  
  }
```

Segundo metodo para listar (el .map)

```
listar() {  
    if (this.state.productos.length > 0) {  
      return this.state.productos.map((e, i) => (  
        <tr key={i}>  
          <td>{e.id_producto}</td>  
          <td>{e.producto}</td>  
          <td>{e.cantidad}</td>  
        </tr>  
      ));  
    }  
  }
```

Laravel 5.7

```
 public function llenarentrada(Request $request, $id_producto)
    {

        $input = $request->all();

            $producto = Producto::find($id_producto);
            if ($producto !=  null ) {
                return response()->json([
                    'ok' => true,
                    'data' => $producto,
                ]);
            } else {
                return response()->json([
                    'ok' => false,
                    'error' => " El producto no existe",
                ]);
            }

    }
```

P.D: Estoy trabajando con laravel como Back-end y ReactJS como Front-end.

Answer (score 0):

Yo he trabajado con problemas parecidos y la solución que he hecho es revisar el estado donde tienes tus items guardados utilizando el identificador único del producto a agregar. Si existe un match suma la cantidad, si no pasa la cantidad nueva. EX:

```
function addNewItem(newItem) {
  //Buscamos en el array de productos si existe el producto nuevo dentro del estado existente  
  let productExist = this.state.productos.find(
    producto => producto.id_producto === newItem.id_producto
  );
  //Si el producto existe
  if (productExist) {
    //Seteamos el estado
    this.setState({
      //Spread del estado antiguo para mantener otras variables
      ...this.state,
      //Alteramos el estado de productos realizando un map de los productos existentes
      productos: this.state.productos.map(producto =>
        //Buscamos el producto que sea igual al nuevo
        producto.id_producto === newItem.id_producto
          ? //Si es igual sumamos cantidades
            { ...newItem, cantidad: producto.cantidad + newItem.cantidad }
          : //Si es distinto retornamos el producto antiguo
            producto
      )
    });
  }
  //Si el producto no existe
  else {
    //Seteamos el estado
    this.setState({
      //Spread del estado antiguo para mantener otras variables
      ...this.state,
      //Alteramos el estado de productos sumando el producto nuevo
      productos: { ...this.state.productos, newItem }
    });
  }
}
```

Existen maneras más elegantes de hacer esto, pero creo que para un ejemplo es mejor algo más explícito. Espero te sirva

Comment: Hola Joaquín, te hago 3 observaciones a tu respuesta: 1. Al usar `setState` no es necesario hacer esto `...this.state` porque esta función ya lo hace de forma implícita. 2. Cuando haces el `map` a productos, no estás retornando nada, por lo que al final quedará una lista de `undefined`, es decir: `[undefined, undefined, undefined]` y 3. En el `else` cuando seteas los productos lo haces con el spread para objetos cuando productos es un arreglo, lo ideal sería: `productos: [ ...this.state.productos, newItem ]` sin `{}`. Debes intentar probar lo que publicas y responder lo que se pregunta